# Tkinter Python Shooting in my game doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

On the up key, the ship should shoot up, I tried to make an animation, but something went wrong: the program does not give an error and nothing happens on the up key.

```
#It works good 
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()
window.title('Star Wars')
c = Canvas(window, width=800, height=600, bg='black')
c.pack()
ship = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 38, 15, fill='red', outline='white')
c.move(ship, 370, 300)
#It doesn't working
def shoot(event):
if event.keysym == 'Up':
    x = 370
    y = 300
        for i in range(9):
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(0.3)
            bullet = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='yellow', outline='black')
            c.move(bullet, x, y)
            c.delete(bullet)
c.bind_all('<Key>', shoot)
```

Comment: because you deleted your bullet using `c.delete`, just after you created it, hence nothing appears. Also, don't use `time.sleep` instead use `<yourwidget>.after` .

Comment: You can add `c.update_idletasks()` before `c.delete(...)`.  Also you should use `c.moveto(...)` instead of `c.move(...)`.  And you should create the bullet once before the for loop and delete it after the for loop.